# Display Drupal content outside Drupal?

Tags: drupal, frameworks, external

Is it possible to use Drupal to feed a few dynamic portions of a mostly static website?  We have a plain old website and are looking to create a sibling site just for web-app stuff (private CMS, databasing, some forms for specific things, etc.).  Some of the content we create on the sibling site (which would be Drupal), we'd like to render in areas on the primary site (non-Drupal).  An example might be a news feed generator that displays on the primary site, but is actually fed from content created in the secondary site's interface.  Another potential workflow might be a Drupal installation that's located in a subdirectory of a mostly static website.  A general login link could redirect users to the drupal area, but could we get any of the content they create outside of that, modularly, so we can keep our nice rigid site design?  I guess I'm looking to harness Drupal as more of a framework than a CMS.

Is any of this possible?  Is this even a logical concept, or am I stupid for asking?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *possible* you could implement a custom callbacks which are accessed via Jquery on your old site.

However....

Why would you do this, Drupal is a CMS for websites, if you have a static website, no matter how big it won't be too dificult to put it into drupal and look the same, even have the same URLs. You then get Drupal goodness wherever and whenever you want very easily.

Comment: Could I get some pointers for easily tossing a site that looks how I want into Drupal and get that Drupal goodness?

Comment: Try this http://acquia.com/community/resources/acquia-tv/tips-and-tricks-drupal-theming-90-minute-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can always access your Drupal database in your external site to display whatever Drupal content you want.

Comment: Only if you also bootstrap Drupal so you can run check_markup() on the text you pull from the database. Unless you only use HTML in your Drupal site. At that point, you could start using node_view() to get a fully built-out node. At that point, see Jeremy French's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could build RSS feeds with Views and put a simple feed parser into your static site. But again, if you want more than simple RSS syndication, you are better off planning a migration path than partial Drupal integration.